# Play Framework 2.2 How set responses Status code in overriding call action

Tags: java, playframework-2.2

I want to create an anotation that will be called in some controllers for checking authentication.

In older play versions until 2.1, i used this following code for overriding call action of Play :

```
public class OAuth2Action extends Action<OAuth2> {

    // ...
    @Override
    public Result call(Http.Context context) throws Throwable
    {
        if (authorization  == null )
            return unauthorized(ACCESS_TOKEN_NOT_FOUND);

        return delegate.call(context);
    }
}
```

It returns Result then it could easily returned unauthorized responses with http status code 401 like in Controller

**In play 2.2 call method was changed and must return F.Promise**

I wrote this following to make it work :

```
public class OAuth2Action extends Action<OAuth2> {
    // ...
    @Override
    public F.Promise<SimpleResult> call(Http.Context context) throws Throwable {    
        if (authorization  == null ) {          
            // return unauthorized(ACCESS_TOKEN_NOT_FOUND); // Now i can't use this
            // I can set Header, Content type, cookies, BUT NOT STATUS CODE
            context.response().setHeader("Header", "test");
        }

        return delegate.call(context);
    }
}
```

I wish to return response with Status code 401, could you help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class OAuth2Action extends Action<OAuth2> {
    // ...
    @Override
    public F.Promise<SimpleResult> call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {
        if (authorization  == null ) {
            return F.Promise.promise(new F.Function0<SimpleResult>() {
                @Override
                public SimpleResult apply() throws Throwable {
                    return unauthorized(ACCESS_TOKEN_NOT_FOUND);
                }
            });
        }
        return delegate.call(ctx);
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I am aware, the promise call can be reduced to `return F.Promise.pure(unauthorized(ACCESS_TOKEN_NOT_FOUND));`

Comment: @knittl, yes F.Promise.pure is also correct and good solution to return already computed (constant) value.